# Cannot Crawl or Update Search Settings with Admin Role (SP2013 On-Premise)

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-search

My search is no longer rendering any documents that have been created within the past couple of months. Apparently, this thing hasn't crawled for a while. I tried to go into

> Central Admin > Content Sources > Reset Index,

and I get this error message.

```
    The search application 'e37bdb38-26e8-5e1d-b5cc-3f797f51f07c' on server JSCOTT-SP01 did not finish loading. 
View the event logs on the affected server for more information.
```

I have no idea what this means or what to do about it. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you checked the log on Search Server ?

Comment: How would I access that? I realize that may seem like an obvious question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by insufficient permissions for the search service account on the SharePoint Server. Verify that no group policies have been set on the local user groups 'WSS_WPG' and 'WSS_ADMIN_WPG'.

Resolution

Check the system event log for group policy changes that may have occurred around the same time as the search errors. Determine if any group policies have altered permissions on 'WSS_WPG', or WSS_ADMIN_WPG groups

```
Log Name:   System
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-GroupPolicy
Event ID:     1502
```

Run the Psconfig command-line tool for SharePoint Products as follows:

```
Psconfig -cmd secureresources
```

[The Search Application Did Not Finish Loading](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2770732)

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am the admin, though. I am using the overlord-level (or whatever the highest permissions are). Yet, somehow, I still lack permissions.

Comment: it is not ur account, it is search service account which permission effected. If it is brand new then might be not setup properly but if this is existing system then chances are some action altered the permission.

Comment: Would it help if I posted what came back in PowerShell?

Comment: powershell mean running the psconfig? if it snot completed successfully then yes

Comment: Ok -- I was using the Central Management Shell. I will respond as soon as a I can -- I have a meeting now. Thank you so much for your time and the help.

Comment: Got this when putting in the prompt.... PS C:\Users\sp-admin> Psconfig -cmd securesources
SharePoint Products Configuration Wizard version 15.0.4569.1503. Copyright (C) M
icrosoft Corporation 2012. All rights reserved.

The securesources command is invalid.

Usage:
        PSCONFIG.EXE -cmd <Command> [Parameters]
        PSCONFIG.EXE -help [Command]
        PSCONFIG.EXE -?
Commands:
setup
standaloneconfig
configdb
helpcollections
secureresources
services
installfeatures
adminvs
upgrade
evalprovision
applicationcontent
quiet
PS C:\Users\sp-admin>

Comment: are you in SharePoint PowerShell? Open the SharePoint PowerShell  as Run as Administrator....then try it

Comment: if that does not work then open the Command Prompt and browse the following path...C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\14\BIN\ and run the command here

Comment: I did it and it's running 5 tasks. It's upgrading everything...it's 10% of task 4/5

Comment: ok let it complete, it is restoring all the permission and required resources.

Comment: It seems like it's going to be a while -- if this works, you are a true genius

Comment: hopefully it should work as it is recommended by the MSFT. on lighter note if it will not work then i am bad guy :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42856/discussion-between-thejdscott-and-waqas-sarwar-mcse).